# Notation of Formal Power Series

Tags: analysis, formal-power-series

I was reading Amann and Escher's Analysis I. I encountered this notation of formal power series on page 72[image] and got confused. 
Could someone please tell me what do the subscript(in this case "n") and the superscript (in this case "m") mean respectively? 

(I was confused because when n = 2, $X_2 = 0$, then $X_2^2 = 0$, but according to the second function, it should equal 1, what's wrong with my reasoning?)

P.S. The definition of the R[[N]] in the question is defined as following in the book
[image]

Comment: You should edit your question to include the definition of a power series. Many readers do not have access to the book.

Comment: @PaulFrost Thank you for your comment! I don't think the author has given an explicit definition of power series (formal power series). He doesn't explain what X mean either. That's part of the reason why I am confused over this notation. The notation came in rather abruptly.  Also, I have searched for this notation on the internet before asking this question. But the notation doesn't seem to be a very common one.

Comment: Do the authors define $R[[X]]$?

Comment: Isn't that just identifying the underlying set of $R[[X]]$ with the sequence space $R^\omega$ and define the multiplication?

Comment: @user10354138 I guess it is, but that information is important to answer the question.

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, I think so. He define R[[X]] as the formal power series ring over R.   The set in the ring is R^N. The addition is defined as the addition of respective coordinates and the multiplication is defined as convolution.

Comment: @PaulFrost I have just edit the question and added the definition of R[[X]].

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you for your comment, I have just edit the question and added the definition of R[[X]]

Comment: Since we are only using $R^\mathbb{N}$, we want to use the indeterminate $X$ instead of working with sequences all the time.  So we make the definition $X$ is the function (or sequence) which is $1$ for $1\in\mathbb{N}$ and $0$ for all other.  $X^m$ is the function (or sequence) which is $1$ for $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $0$ for others.  The superscript $m$ in $X^m_n$ is the power of $X$ and the subscript $n$ is the $n$-th coefficient/coordinate.  You can check all the usual rules work.

Comment: Thinking as a teacher, I say that this definition shows the foolishness of defining a concept in the abstractest way possible.If I were writing such a book, I would have first said that power series behave just like polynomials, except that there are potentially infinitely many terms. Then I would immediately have given some simple examples, like $\frac1{1-x}$ and its square $1+2x + 3x^2+\cdots$. Only at this point would I have introduced the abstract definition that you had to deal with. No wonder you had trouble understanding it.

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you for your answer! I calculate again. I understand it now. :)

Comment: @Lubin Thank you for your comment. Yes, I totally agree with you. Btw, this book doesn't always behave like this. It usually supports the readers with concrete examples to help understand an abstract concept. This is one of the rare occasions that it doesn't do so. I just had a peek into the new edition of this book (which is only available in German). In the new edition they rewrote this part. It's still very confusing in the new edition but it shows they must have noticed that the formulation in the old edition needs improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R[[X]]$ is introduced in a very formal and abstract but absolutely correct way. According to this definition an element of $R[[X]]$ is nothing else than an infinite sequence $\mathbf r= (r_0,r_1,r_2,\ldots)$ with $r_i \in R$.

$X$ is defined as the sequence $(0,1,0, 0,\ldots)$. Its $m$-th power $X^m$ in the ring $R[[X]]$ is given as $(0,\ldots,0,1,0,,0,\ldots)$ where $1$ occurs at position $m$. Then $X^0 = (1,0,0,\ldots)$, $X^1 = X$, $X^2 = (0,0,1,0,\ldots)$ etc.

An arbitrary element of $R[[X]]$ is then usually written as
$$\mathbf r = (r_0,r_1,r_2,\ldots) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty r_mX^m .$$
Note, however, that *infinite sums* in general do not exist in $R[[X]]$. An infinite sum
$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty\mathbf r_m$$
is well-defined precisely if for each $i$ the number of $\mathbf r_m$ with $i$-th coordinate $(\mathbf r_m)_i \ne 0$ is finite.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out after you point out the the definition of R[[X]] is the key to the problem. I think the main reason that I was confused is because the operation of convolution is still very unfamiliar to me. Also, the note is very thought provoking. I haven't thought about that yet. Again, thank you for your detailed answer and comments!

Comment: @outis If you understand a formal power series as an expression $\sum_{m=0}^\infty\mathbf r_mX^m$ without caring what $X$ is, then you see what happens if multiply two such "sums": Collecting all $m$-th powers of $X$ you get the coefficients by convolution. That is the motivation for the definition in your book.